# Drawing a line graph

Tags: pgfplots, errors, graphs, sidewaysfigure

For an unknown reason the code doesn't compile.

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=Month,
                ylabel=Rainfall (mm),
                ymin=80,
                ymax=450,
                date coordinates in=x,
                xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=near xticklabel},
                xticklabel={\month},
                date ZERO=2021.12.31, % reference date
                xtick={
                    2022-01-01,
                    2022-02-01,
                    2022-03-01,
                    2022-04-01,
                    2022-05-01,
                    2022-06-01,
                    2022-07-01,
                    2022-08-01,
                    2022-09-01,
                    2022-10-01,
                    2022-11-01,
                    2022-12-01
                },
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=45,anchor=north east},
            ]
                \addplot coordinates {
                    (2022-01-01, 81.9)
                    (2022-02-01, 70)
                    (2022-03-01, 104.9)
                    (2022-04-01, 276.2)
                    (2022-05-01, 311.6)
                    (2022-06-01, 201.5)
                    (2022-07-01, 132.5)
                    (2022-08-01, 108.5)
                    (2022-09-01, 248.8)
                    (2022-10-01, 399.1)
                    (2022-11-01, 362.4)
                    (2022-12-01, 165.1)
                };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Average Monthly Total Rainfall}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! To help people help you, please complete your code rather than just giving a fragment so people can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. Also, that's not an error code.

Comment: Please don't downvote new users' posts within *minutes* of posting and without even providing any feedback on how they might be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are close. Kindly see my changes below:

- used `standalone`, which is more gentle when developing graphics (switch back later)
- commented out almost everything inside the `axis`, until it compiled without error (and empty content)
- the line containing `2022-08-01` said, it can't deal with the `8` (and the ones thereafter)
- added `\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}`, reentered said dataline
- finally the code shown below compiled

So finetuning is still needed. I suggest to remove the comments (=line deletions) step-by-step-with-compiles to ensure, it still compiles AND things move into the right direction.

This way you can localize problems when they occure (and sometimes it's a good idea to disable those lines and leave solutions for later ... often they are gone, anyway).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}% <<< perhaps you used it already?

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
%            xlabel=Month,
%            ylabel=Rainfall (mm),
%            ymin=80,
%            ymax=450,
            date coordinates in=x,% <<< was necessary
%            xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=near xticklabel},
%            xticklabel={\month},
%            date ZERO=2021.12.31, % reference date
%            xtick={
%                2022-01-01,
%                2022-02-01,
%                2022-03-01,
%                2022-04-01,
%                2022-05-01,
%                2022-06-01,
%                2022-07-01,
%                2022-08-01,
%                2022-09-01,
%                2022-10-01,
%                2022-11-01,
%                2022-12-01
%            },
%            xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=45,anchor=north east},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
                (2022-01-01, 81.9)
                (2022-02-01, 70)
                (2022-03-01, 104.9)
                (2022-04-01, 276.2)
                (2022-05-01, 311.6)
                (2022-06-01, 201.5)
                (2022-07-01, 132.5)
                (2022-08-01, 108.5)
                (2022-09-01, 248.8)
                (2022-10-01, 399.1)
                (2022-11-01, 362.4)
                (2022-12-01, 165.1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```